# List of Id's with no dependency in Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have a scenario in spring-mongo query. Mongo version is `3.2`

Application have two collections (Collection A and Collection B).

```
**Sample contents**
Collection A :: {"_id":1, "name":"content 1"}...{"_id":100, "name":"content 100"}

Collection B :: {"_id":1, "name":"parent 1", "a":[1,2,58,67]}
{"_id":2, "name":"parent 2", "a":[2,85,96,99]}
```

Collection B holds reference ids of Collection A as a array.

**Scenario:**
 I will past list of ids of Collection A to the query: I need to get list of ids of Collection A which are not associated anywhere in Collection B.
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am planning to proceed with Aggregation with following query.. Looking up with 
preserveNullAndEmptyArrays saving my day.

```
  db.a.aggregate([
        { 
            $match: { "_id":{$in:["1","5","10"]} } 
        },
        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: "b",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "a",
              as: "moneyid"
            }
        },
        {
         $unwind:
            {"path":"$moneyid", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}
         },
         {
         $match:{
             "moneyid":{$eq:null}
             }
         }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the following approach

1) Find Unique Id's in Collection B which are in array "a":[]

2) Execute a find query in Collection A - Use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) in the find query and pass all the ids which you obtained from array "a":[] from Collection B

Note:If you need to find matching documents between two collections then you can use $lookup which works like a left outer join.

Comment: Thank you for your input. My application collection will be very huge in size. So I am slightly hesitant to look through entire collection.